# Why can't I get swig wrap std::vector to Ruby class?

Tags: ruby, stl, swig

I have an application with an embedded Ruby interpreter, and interfaces to STL classes generated by swig.
Pretty much everything worked out fine thanks to swig, except for one thing:

```
%module Stuff
%import "std_vector.i"
namespace std
{
  %template(Vectord) vector<double>;
}; 

%inline%{
  std::vector<double> test;
%}
```

When I try to use this in Ruby the type `Stuff::Vectord` exists, but it is not the return type of the generated singleton method test. Looking at the generated C wrapper file I can see the class `Vectord` and its methods getting defined, but looking at `_wrap_test_get` I do not see anything returning `sth` of class `Stuff::Vectord`.

What do I have to do to get `test` typed as `Vectord`?

Comment: I've worked with your example and I don't see any problem in generating either ruby or C# output. It is true that you don't see any special Vectord type in your swig generated output for the test() function, but it is returning the correct type. I've learned that doing a test with C# and exploring the types used in the *.cs wrappers can be a good sanity check for your SWIG'd code.

Answer (score 3):

First, you are correct. The ruby generated `Stuff::test` object is not of type `Vectord`.

*However*, it is of a type that behaves exactly like `Vectord` which is the most important question for a duck typed language like Ruby.

#### Correction to Stuff.i

There is one minor problem in your example. The `%import <stl_vector.i>` statement should be `%include <stl_vector.i>`.

The correct complete example is:

```
%module Stuff
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std
{
  %template(Vectord) vector<double>;
}; 

%inline%{
  std::vector<double> test;
%}
```

#### Building the Module

The swig wrapper can be generated with

```
swig -ruby -c++ Stuff.i
```

And compiled (with g++) with the statement:

```
g++ Stuff_wrap.cxx -shared -fPIC -o Stuff.so -I /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/
```

#### Using the Module

```
jason@jason-VirtualBox:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'Stuff'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Stuff::test.class
=> Array
```

As we can see, the object returned by `Stuff::test` is of type `Array`. However, unlike a regular Ruby array, this array can only be set to a value that is convertible to a `std::vector<double>`

```
irb(main):002:0> Stuff::test = [5,4,3]
=> [5, 4, 3]
irb(main):003:0> Stuff::test = [5.0, "5.0"]
TypeError: double
    from (irb):3:in `test='
    from (irb):3
    from :0
```

Also, it can be converted directly to and from `std::vector<double>` objects.

```
irb(main):002:0> vec = Stuff::Vectord.new()
=> std::vector<double,std::allocator< double > > []
irb(main):003:0> vec << 5.0
=> 5.0
irb(main):004:0> vec << 2.3
=> 2.3
irb(main):005:0> vec
=> std::vector<double,std::allocator< double > > [5.0,2.3]
irb(main):006:0> Stuff::test = vec
=> std::vector<double,std::allocator< double > > [5.0,2.3]
irb(main):007:0> vec2 = Stuff::Vectord.new(Stuff::test)
=> std::vector<double,std::allocator< double > > [5.0,2.3]
irb(main):008:0> Stuff::test.class
=> Array
irb(main):009:0> vec2.class
=> Stuff::Vectord
irb(main):010:0> Stuff::test
=> [5.0, 2.3]
```

#### Other SWIG Targets

It's important to note that the statically typed SWIG targets of C# and Java produce the results you were expecting. If you ever have a question about how your types are being handled in a SWIG output, it is almost always a good idea to compare the C# or Java output against what you are expecting.

#### Conclusion

While `Stuff::test` and `Vectord` are two different types, they both are arrays that can only store doubles.

They are almost indistinguishable inside of the Ruby code. The code produced does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: You said you changed %import to %include, but the "correct complete example" still shows "%import". Was that an oversight?